# Linking curl after compiling fails in netbeans build

Tags: c++, netbeans, curl, build, cygwin

if i try this

```
g++ -o testApp main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz
```

it works perfect...

BUT if i want to run my sample app by using netbeans directly it gives me some errors.

here a part of Makefile-Debug.mk

```
# Build Targets
.build-conf: ${BUILD_SUBPROJECTS}
    "${MAKE}"  -f nbproject/Makefile-${CND_CONF}.mk ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/SampleApp.exe

${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/SampleApp.exe: ${OBJECTFILES}
    ${MKDIR} -p ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}
    ${LINK.cc} -I/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz -o ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/SampleApp ${OBJECTFILES} ${LDLIBSOPTIONS}

${OBJECTDIR}/main.o: main.cpp
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}
    ${RM} $@.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) -g -MMD -MP -MF $@.d -o ${OBJECTDIR}/main.o main.cpp
```

result of netbeans build output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/SampleApp.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/SampleApp.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
g++.exe     -I/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz -o dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/SampleApp build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o -L/usr/local/lib
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_setopt'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_perform'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp'
/cygdrive/c/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SampleApp/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `_curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/SampleApp.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

what can be wrong here...?

Comment: fixed it with this order `${LINK.cc} -o ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/gamedbot ${OBJECTFILES} -I/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz ${LDLIBSOPTIONS}` this works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -L option needs to be before the library you specify with -l on the command line.

So if you need -L/usr/local/lib for libcurl (as in your small sample) you need to *first* specify -L to the correct dir and then -l with the correct lib name.

Comment: well i have tried it but the linking is fine. the order takes no effect to the result.

Compiling:
`$(COMPILE.cc) -g -MMD -MP -MF $@.d -o ${OBJECTDIR}/main.o main.cpp`

Linking:
`${LINK.cc} ${LDLIBSOPTIONS} -I/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz -o ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/SampleApp ${OBJECTFILES}`

i think there is something wrong with the compiling

Comment: the "linking is fine" but yet you get the errors from ld? Sorry, you've lost me...

Comment: thank you anyway. yes the order of options i offer g++ takes no effect. there is no difference if i first offer `-lcurl` and then `-L/usr/local/lib` or in reversed order. it seems like g++ is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: sorry, but the order _is_ significant (see man page and more), and if it isn't in your case then something else is special for you

Comment: For anyone who sees this in the future, in netbeans you can add the -lcurl to your properties=>build->Linker->libraries to have it appended to the end of the compiler command correctly.